# Rails Logs: Only show Create, Update, and Destroy SQL statements in Logs and nothing else

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I only want to see CREATE/UPDATE/DESTROY-related sql statements in the logs.  I do not want any READ-related statements, caches, or any other information displayed in the logs because it is making it tough to sift through.

Currently within `app/config/environments/production.rb` I have the following configuration set which shows way too much in the logs:

```
config.log_level = :debug
```

The default config for production shows too little information.  It ignores all the sql statements I want to see:

```
# shows too little information
config.log_level = :info
```

Is there a configuration setting in rails to have the logs output only the information I want to see?  If not: how might I do this?

Comment: read this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#log-levels

Comment: @uDaY Thanks.  I did read this.  It does not appear that there currently exists a log level for what I am looking for, and it does not appear to have much guidance on how to implement a custom log level.

Comment: You could set the log level to `:info` and subscribe to [`sql.active_record`](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_instrumentation.html#sql-active-record) events and send all manually events to the log that do not start with `SELECT`...

Comment: @spickermann, that sounds like it would work.  Would you mind elaborating on how to "subscribe" to sql.active_record events and send the events to the log?  I am not sure of what code to write to do that or where to put that code.

Comment: @Neil: Sure, please see my answer...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can disable logging of `ActiveRecord` database queries by setting the `log_level` to `:info`.

Then use Rails' `ActiveSupport::Instrumentation` and subscribe to the [`sql.active_record`](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_instrumentation.html#sql-active-record) event.

Just add the following code into an initializer:

```
# in `config/initializers/query_logger.rb`
class QueryLogger
  def call(name, started, finished, unique_id, payload)
    query = payload[:sql]

    Rails.logger.info("SQL Query: #{query}") unless query.start_with?('SELECT')
  end
end

ActiveSupport::Notifications.subscribe('sql.active_record', QueryLogger.new)
```

Comment: This works great.  The only thing I wish it did was show the values within the SQL Query statement.  This implementation currently doesn't do that.  Any tips on how to make this work would be awesome.  Example of an SQL Log statement with this setup:  `Info -- : SQL Query: UPDATE "blogs" SET "name" = ?, "age" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "blogs"."id" = ?`    So notice how it doesn't show the `name`, `age`, `updated_at` `blogs.id` values.  It would be perfect if it did.

Comment: In [the docs](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_instrumentation.html#sql-active-record) you can see that the payload does not only return `sql`, but also `name`, an `id` and `binds` (binding`). I didn't test it, but I would be too surprised if you found this information in the `binds`. You might want to try to log that values too.